# Calculate distance from a point to a MultiLineString geometry - PYQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to calculate the distance from a point to the closest river in my QGIS plugin. But I receive this message: `MultiLineString geometry cannot be converted to a point. Only Point types are permitted.` I can understand the cause of this message, but I don't know how to calculate the distance from a point and a MultiLineString geometry.

This is my code:

```
def getPointFromFeature(self, featureID, layer):
  expr = QgsExpression("Id = '"+featureID+"'")          
  selection = self.selectionByExpr(layer,expr)
  geom = selection[0].geometry().asPoint()
  return geom

def getDistances(self, geom1, geom2):
  d = QgsDistanceArea()
  d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
  measure=d.measureLine(geom1, geom2)/1000
  measure=round(measure,1)
  return str(measure)

def getRiversDistances(self, featureID):
  layerFiumi = self.getLayerFiumi()
  layerBeni = self.getLayerBeni()
  geomBene = self.getPointFromFeature(featureID, layerBeni)
  expr = QgsExpression("type = 'river'") 
  selection = self.selectionByExpr(layerFiumi, expr)
  d = {}      
  for river in selection:
    d[river[1]] = self.getDistances(geomBene, river.geometry().asPoint())  
  return str(d)
```

Comment: Just get distance to multilinestring geometry without trying to cast it into point. The function should find the closest point of the river automatically.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I did like you said, but when I call `d.measureLine(geom1, geom2)` it says: `argument 2 has unexpected type 'QgsGeometry'`

Comment: `measureLine()` requires two points. So, I need to find the closest point of the river to my point (I don't know how) or I need to find something different from `measureLine()`

Comment: `layerBeni` is a point layer and `layerFiumi` is a multiline layer, right?

Comment: yes it's right Kadir!

Comment: `Distance` should work as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuMJ8qEd8pM.

Comment: Do you need distances on ellipsoid? Why I ask that because you use `setEllipsoid('WGS84')`. If you don't need that, the video linked in @user30184's comment must be sufficient for you. If you need them on ellipsoid, then it is a bit complicated. `QgsDistanceArea` has no any method which gives you closest point on the line (on ellipsoid).

Comment: I used `setEllipsoid('WGS84')` because I need kilometers for unit.

Comment: geom1.distance(geom2) should give distance of geom2 from geom1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed names of variables to be more eligible/legible for other readers.

```
def getPointFromFeature(self, featureID, layer):
  expr = QgsExpression("Id = '"+featureID+"'")          
  selection = self.selectionByExpr(layer, expr)
  geom = selection[0].geometry() # removed asPoint()
  return geom

def getDistances(self, point_geom, river_geom):
  d = QgsDistanceArea()
  d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

  # Added/changed next two code lines.
  # Line A
  nearest_point_on_river = river_geom.nearestPoint(point_geom)
  # Line B
  measure = d.measureLine(point_geom.asPoint(), nearest_point_on_river.asPoint()) / 1000

  measure = round(measure, 1)
  return str(measure)

def getRiversDistances(self, featureID):
  river_layer = self.getLayerFiumi()
  point_layer = self.getLayerBeni()
  point_geom  = self.getPointFromFeature(featureID, point_layer)
  expr = QgsExpression("type = 'river'") 
  selection = self.selectionByExpr(river_layer, expr)
  d = {}      
  for river in selection:
    d[river[1]] = self.getDistances(point_geom, river.geometry())  # removed asPoint()
  return str(d)
```

I think this script will solve two errors problem: `MultiLineString geometry cannot be converted to a point. Only Point types are permitted.` and `argument 2 has unexpected type 'QgsGeometry'`.

Note that `Line A` calculates the nearest point using plain geometry and `Line B` calculates the distance on ellipsoid. This is not a perfect solution, but I guess it is sufficient for your goal.

Comment: Thanks again, this solution is very good for my aim.